# Test stream bridge fails when the output binding destination is the same as the input destination

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I have the following configuration

```
  bindings:
    receiveEvents-in-0:
      destination: internal
      group: a-certain-group
    sendMessages-out-0:
      destination: internal
  rabbit:
    bindings:
      receiveEvents-in-0:
        consumer:
          bindingRoutingKey: 'bla'
      sendMessages-out-0:
        producer:
          routingKeyExpression: headers['routing-key']
```

Stream bridge test

```
@SpringBootTest
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)
class StreamBridgeIntegrationTest {

private static final int TIMEOUT = 1000;

@Autowired
private OutputDestination output;

@Test
void test() throws IOException {
    var message = // a certain message with routing key header
    streamBridge.send("internal", message);
    var sentMessage = output.receive(TIMEOUT, "internal").getPayload(); // this is returning null
    // asserts
}
```

I tried the following:

- Sending messages using the binding name

  ```
  streamBridge.send("sendMessages-out-0", message); // did not work
  var sentMessage = output.receive(TIMEOUT, "sendMessages-out-0").getPayload(); // still returning null
  ```
- Change the destination in the config for the binding

  ```
    bindings:
        receiveEvents-in-0:
          destination: internal
          group: a-certain-group
        sendMessages-out-0:
          destination: random
  ```

  ```
    streamBridge.send("random", message); // worked
    var sentMessage = output.receive(TIMEOUT, "random").getPayload(); // returned the message
  ```
- Commented out the input config

  ```
    bindings:
    #    receiveEvents-in-0:
    #      destination: internal
    #      group: a-certain-group
        sendMessages-out-0:
          destination: internal
  ```

  ```
    streamBridge.send("internal", message); // worked
    var sentMessage = output.receive(TIMEOUT, "internal").getPayload(); // returned the message
  ```

The final two worked and made the test green but that is not what I intend the behavior to be. I want to send messages to destination = internal (I have configured a rabbitMQ topic exchange with that name) and receive messages from the same destination (with specified routing key)
I'm choosing the routing carefully because i'm not interested in listening to messages that my application publishes. The consumer here is intended to listen to messages that are coming from outside the cluster.

Any idea how to solve this? is logically wrong as well to use the same destination for input and output?

Additional info:

- spring boot version 2.7.0
- spring cloud version 2021.0.3
- RabbitMQ binder

Answer (score 0):

While you can certainly do it. . .

```
@Test
void test_SO() throws Exception {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new SpringApplicationBuilder(
            TestChannelBinderConfiguration.getCompleteConfiguration(EmptyConfiguration.class))
        .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
        .run("--spring.jmx.enabled=false")) {

        StreamBridge streamBridge = context.getBean(StreamBridge.class);
        streamBridge.send("foo", "hello");
        OutputDestination output = context.getBean(OutputDestination.class);
        Message<byte[]> result = output.receive(1000, "foo");
        assertThat(result).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

. .  I am wondering why?
Remember, `StreamBridge` was designed for a very specific use cases to facilitate integration with external systems that do not have a corresponding binders. All other cases are much easier addressed without `StreamBridge`.